# Mediawiki: Circular dependency when creating service

Tags: mediawiki-extensions

I have a custom mediawiki extension which defines the function:

```
function SuggestionAddMagicWord($prefix, $word, $function)
{
    global $wgParser;
    $wgParser->setFunctionHook($prefix . $word, $function);
}
```

Mediawiki stops with the error:

```
MediaWiki internal error.

Original exception: [YhP_NvoN5s_lyujNdKJXlAAAAAY] /wiki/Cathopedia:Pagina_principale Wikimedia\Services\RecursiveServiceDependencyException: Recursive service instantiation: Circular dependency when creating service! Parser -> Parser
Backtrace:
from /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(437)
#0 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(416): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->createService()
#1 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/MediaWikiServices.php(279): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->getService()
#2 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/MediaWikiServices.php(1287): MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices->getService()
#3 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/Setup.php(843): MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices->getParser()
#4 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/vendor/wikimedia/object-factory/src/ObjectFactory/ObjectFactory.php(232): {closure}()
#5 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/StubObject.php(135): Wikimedia\ObjectFactory\ObjectFactory::getObjectFromSpec()
#6 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/DeprecatedGlobal.php(59): StubObject->_newObject()
#7 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/StubObject.php(223): DeprecatedGlobal->_newObject()
#8 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/StubObject.php(119): StubObject->_unstub()
#9 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/StubObject.php(149): StubObject->_call()
#10 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/w-1.37/extensions-custom/Suggestion/Suggestion.php(45): StubObject->__call()
#11 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/w-1.37/extensions-custom/Suggestion/Suggestion.php(37): SuggestionAddMagicWord()
#12 /var/wwwc/cathopedia.org/mediawiki-1.37.1/includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(338): SuggestionSetup()
```

code line #10 refers to the above function.

Everythng was fine in mediawiki 1.31, but with 1.37 I get this error.

What is happening? what should I do?

Comment: Which hook calls `function SuggestionAddMagicWord($prefix, $word, $function)`?

Comment: maybe `ParserFirstCallInit`? `LanguageGetMagic`?

Comment: I expected you know that, having written or at least studied your "custom mediawiki extension".